# C#. Как отследить использование диска?

Tags: c#, .net

В диспетчере задач, во вкладке производительность можно нажать на "Диск 0 (c:)". Как получить переменную с его активным временем в процентах?

Comment: изучайте MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountertype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте для этого [`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx), а так же вам будет эта ссылка: [Tracking Windows Performance Counters by application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/faber/2014/11/20/tracking-windows-performance-counters-by-application/).